# Desciptor values are true

Tags: javascript, object, oop

```js
let obj = {windows : 10,wheels : 100,seats : 99};
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'wheels'))
```

Output:

```
Object { value: 100, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true }
```

I read on an article that the default values of an object's descriptor are false, but the following code shows otherwise. Can someone tell me the mistake?

Comment: The default values are false only when you create a property with `Object.defineProperty` or `Object.defineProperties` methods.

Comment: The default values are `false` when you create properties with `Object.defineProperty()`, not when you use an ordinary object initializer.

Answer (score 1):

> I read on an article that the default values of an object's descriptor are false...

That's only when you call [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) or its cousin [`defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) (or use the second argument of [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)), the defaults for the flags in the descriptor object are all `false`:

```js
let obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "wheels", {
    value: 100,
});
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "wheels"))
```

When you create a property via direct assignment as you are in the question, they all default to `true`.